# How to solve "Error establishing a database connection" with wordpress and mysql running in docker

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker

I'm trying to run wordpress and mysql on a ubuntu server, both running in docker and ran via docker-compose.

Everything works locally, but when I moved the files to a Ubuntu server, I'm now getting "Error establishing a database connection".

I run `docker-compose up -d` to run the following docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "80:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |
        define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
        define('MULTISITE', true);
        define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
        define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'example.com');
        define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/site/');
        define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
        define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
        define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com/wordpress' );
        define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

Reference to how I came to this compose structure: https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/

`docker logs` shows:
`WordPress database error Table 'wordpress.wp_blogs' doesn't exist for query SELECT  wp_blogs.blog_id FROM wp_blogs`

How can I solve this issue so that the wordpress container is aware of the mysql docker container?

Comment: Try removing the :3306 from the DB_HOST.

Comment: Thanks @shn, I tried this but I still ran into the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Try to Specify custom network 
you will find the solution as here 
[Docker Custom  Networking](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks)

Comment: By default all services in compose are connected to default network so this is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 spaces after

> WORDPRESS_DB_HOST:

Comment: ohh. I leave only a space after the colon. works for me